# How to redirect a user to a visited sub-domain on his next visit to main domain

Tags: redirection, multi-sites, cookies

I have a website say example.com with 5 sub-domains: site1.example.com, site2.example.com, site3.example.com, site4.example.com, and site5.example.com.

When users visit example.com, they are presented with the other 5 sub-domains to choose from. I want to implement something that redirect the users to the sub-domain they choose the first time they visit the main domain. I know I can use cookies for this, but how can I implement this in Drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implementation of `hook_init()` should be present on your subdomains but not on your main domain:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_init() {
  if(!isset($_COOKIE['your_cookie_name'])) {
    /*Your need to set cookie for your main domain, as well as for all your subdomains otherwise once a user visits another subdomain by typing the url directly in the address bar the cookie would be overwritten*/
    setcookie('your_cookie_name', base64_encode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']), YOUR_EXPIRATION_TIME, '/', 'example.com');
    setcookie('your_cookie_name', base64_encode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']), YOUR_EXPIRATION_TIME, '/', 'site1.example.com');
    setcookie('your_cookie_name', base64_encode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']), YOUR_EXPIRATION_TIME, '/', 'site2.example.com');
    ...
    setcookie('your_cookie_name', base64_encode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']), YOUR_EXPIRATION_TIME, '/', 'site5.example.com');
  }
  else {
    header('Location: ' . base64_decode($_COOKIE['your_cookie_name']));
  }
}
```

Your main domain should have a module with the following code:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_init() {
  if(isset($_COOKIE['your_cookie_name'])) {
    header('Location: ' . base64_decode($_COOKIE['your_cookie_name']));
  }
}
```

I didn't test this code, but I am positive it should work, or at the very least it illustrates the approach.

Comment: Alex,thanks for giving me the idea/approach.I will try this and get back ASAP.

Comment: I just added a small portion of code to my answer. Forgot to include the code for main domain :)

Comment: i tried the above code but it seems not to be redirecting properly. For-instance i get this http://example.com/site1.example.com on my next visit.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: in the first code snippet replace: base64_encode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) with base64_encode("http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']). I think this should work then.

Comment: I replaced the code as you said but i get this info in my browser "This webpage has a redirect loop".it fails to redirect to the previous visited link.Hmmm,any other suggestion.

Comment: The module implementation finally works well.thank you Alex for the idea and guidance.